# How do you use punctuation when describing something using three words?

Tags: punctuation

"Humans are a large complex organism" how would I correctly use punctuation here?

Comment: You’d put a period at the end of the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

In a sentence like this, you only need to place a comma between 'large' and 'complex' - i.e. "Humans are a large, complex organism". (As a matter of clarity, though, I'd omit the article 'a' and make 'organism' plural - i.e. "Humans are large, complex organisms" - otherwise you imply that the whole collective of humans are one huge organism.